# How do I convert HTML file (theme) to WordPress so that I can manage all elements?

Tags: html, wordpress

Here is my website, I want to convert into WordPress so that later, from WordPress admin page, I can manage all elements like skill bars, 'P' tags withing skill bars, images, heading etc.

http://rohitpanchal-com.stackstaging.com/

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/

Comment: google is your best friend!

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you learn how to create a WordPress theme. A WordPress theme handles how the content you enter in the Dashboard gets displayed to visitors.

I recommend you take a look at [The Theme Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/) from WordPress.

Here's a formal tutorial if that suits you better: [WordPress Development for Beginners: Building Themes](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/theme-development/)

Good luck!

Comment: When your answer includes an off-site tutorial, you should immediately think "oh, this question is off-topic on SO!" since requests for off-site tutorials are explicitly off-topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic